# How do I migrate Calendar events from one Outlook calendar to another, while preserving Tracking info?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I need to migrate calendar events from one Outlook account (local) to another (Office365.com).

I know how to copy/paste items, and how to export/import the calendar items. But none of these methods preserve my calendar item's **Tracking information** (i.e. who accepted/denied the meeting request).

How do I migrate calendar items while preserving this important tracking info?

I use Outlook 2010. Both servers are Exchange servers (one 2003, one Office365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure this out. Eventually we captured tracking information as part of the meeting description, just so we have it on record. And then we copied the calendar items across.

Comment: Did you manage automatically copy all the events from one calendar to another, for past and future events? If so, can you share how?